# Как конвертировать список символов в строку?

Tags: python

У меня есть такой list: `['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', ' ', 'W', 'O', 'R', 'L', 'D']`

Как конвертировать его в: `"HELLO WORLD"`

Answer (score 7):

С помощью метода строк [join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm):

```
chars =  ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', ' ', 'W', 'O', 'R', 'L', 'D']
word = ''.join(chars)
```